# jQuery context not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-selectors

Doing this using $(CommandLineAPI querySelector) in Chrome devtools works as expected:

`$('body', iframe.contentDocument) // <body></body>`

It gets the iframe's body.

Doing the same with jQuery doesn't:

`jQuery('body', iframe.contentDocument) // Empty jQuery result`

Is there any way I can achieve the same functionality outside the devTools?

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(iframe)`. Does it show the correct iframe?

Comment: Yes, it also shows if I log iframe.contentDocument

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to access it before it's ready? Try attaching an event handler on the iframe to make sure the jQuery is executed after the iframe has loaded.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer. If that's what you're using, please be sure to mark it as an answer (Or simply add your own, for future visitors to use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you access the iframe after it's ready.

```
jQuery(iframe).load(function() {
    //Iframe is now loaded, so jQuery should be able to access the DOM:
    jQuery('body', iframe.contentDocument)
});
```